# Detecting midi controller pads in Quartz Composer

Tags: midi, quartz-composer

I'm trying to use the 8 pads and 8 knobs of my Akai LPD8 MIDI controller in Quartz Composer, so that I can easily control patch parameters.

I have successfully mapped the 8 knobs, via a `MIDI Controller Receiver` patch, and the `Learn Controller` button: this added 1 parameter to the patch for each knob.

Unfortunately, the 8 pads aren't detected in the `Learn` mode, and I haven't been able to map them to patch parameters in any way.

Do you know how to do this?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Use must activate one of the PAD/PROG CHNG/CC modes to configure what kind of message the pads send. (Learning Note-On or Program Change messages would not make sense.)

Comment: Thank you for that answer. I'm a beginner with Quartz Composer, so I would need more details to understand what you mean. Could you please detail the steps more clearly, and ideally also give an example of a composition where a patch's color is set to "red" by hitting a pad? That would really help!

Comment: You forgot to press "CC".

Comment: From what you write, I understand that "CC" is a button in the Quartz Composer interface. Where exactly in that interface?

Comment: No, it's the button labeled "CC" on the LPD8.

Comment: It worked! Note that by default, the controller was assigning the same CC value for some of the pads and knobs. In order to differentiate the pad from the knob, I had to override some of those CC values via the controller's software. If you update your answer reflecting those findings, I think it would make it clearer for future readers. I'll accept it as a solution.